# invalid procedure call or argument when calling function in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

There's a command button as a trigger to send email to customers when you click on it. It will call the function first like this:

```
Private Sub Lotus2_Click()
ThisWorkbook.Send_Unformatted_Rangedata (2)
End Sub
```

Then there are two parts for the function in another sheet waiting to be called, I couldn't debug this since whenever I want to, the system only show me the line which calls the function. The problem is I know there's something wrong about calling function, but I'm not sure which part of the function goes wrong. I'm sorry as the function part is a bit tedious, as you can see below. I will truly appreciate a lot for any advice given, thanks.

*********UPDATE*******************
Hi, I just found something wrong with this line with the error message of`Run time error -2147417851 (80010105) Automation error The server threw an exception`:

```
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument
```

But I don't see anything wrong with it. Any help will be appreciated much.

```
Sub Send_Unformatted_Rangedata(i As Integer)
Dim noSession As Object, noDatabase As Object, noDocument As Object
Dim vaRecipient As Variant
Dim rnBody As Range
Dim Data As DataObject
Dim rngGen As Range
Dim rngApp As Range
Dim rngspc As Range

Dim stSubject As String
stSubject = "E-Mail For Approval for " + (Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) + "  for the Project  " + Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
'Const stMsg As String = "Data as part of the e-mail's body."
'Const stPrompt As String = "Please select the range:"

'This is one technique to send an e-mail to many recipients but for larger
'number of recipients it's more convenient to read the recipient-list from
'a range in the workbook.
 vaRecipient = VBA.Array(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "U").Value, Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "V").Value)

On Error Resume Next
'Set rnBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=stPrompt, _
     Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
'The user canceled the operation.
'If rnBody Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set rngGen = Nothing
Set rngApp = Nothing
Set rngspc = Nothing

Set rngGen = Sheets("General Overview").Range("A1:C30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rngApp = Sheets("Application").Range("A1:E13").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Set rngspc = Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "Q").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rngspc = Union(rngspc, Sheets(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "P").Value).Range(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "R").Value).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

 On Error GoTo 0

If rngGen Is Nothing And rngApp Is Nothing And rngspc Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
           vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If


'Instantiate Lotus Notes COM's objects.
Set noSession = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Set noDatabase = noSession.GETDATABASE("", "")

'Make sure Lotus Notes is open and available.
 If noDatabase.IsOpen = False Then noDatabase.OPENMAIL

'Create the document for the e-mail.
Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument

'Copy the selected range into memory.
rngGen.Copy
rngApp.Copy
rngspc.Copy

'Retrieve the data from then copied range.
Set Data = New DataObject
Data.GetFromClipboard

'Add data to the mainproperties of the e-mail's document.
With noDocument
  .Form = "Memo"
  .SendTo = vaRecipient
  .Subject = stSubject
  'Retrieve the data from the clipboard.
  .Body = Data.GetText & " " & stMsg
  .SaveMessageOnSend = True
End With

'Send the e-mail.
With noDocument
  .PostedDate = Now()
  .send 0, vaRecipient
End With

'Release objects from memory.
Set noDocument = Nothing
Set noDatabase = Nothing
Set noSession = Nothing


'Activate Excel for the user.
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"

'Empty the clipboard.
Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "The e-mail has successfully been created and distributed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Change your error options in the VBE to break in class modules, then try again to locate the actual error line.

Comment: @Rory Thank you so much, I'm able to debug the actual error already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then there are two parts for the function in another sheet

If the procedures are located in a sheet module, then you should call them with:

`Sheet_Object_Name.Send_Unformatted_Rangedata (2)`

Second option is to move procedures to `ThisWorkbook` module, and your code:

`ThisWorkbook.Send_Unformatted_Rangedata (2)`

should work fine.

Another solution is to add a separate module to your project (using `Insert->Module`), move procedures there, and then you can call those procedures from other modules using simply:

`Send_Unformatted_Rangedata (2)`

Comment: thx for your advice, I will consider move to the last part which is very handy for me. Now I got an error on `Set noDocument = noDatabase.CreateDocument`, do you think anything wrong with it?

Comment: @vivixu I'm afraid I can't help you with Lotus Notes automation, but since it's not related to the original question, I would suggest to: a) create a separate question b) include only a part of code required to reproduce the issue c) include the error message.

Comment: Thank you, due to the time interval restriction, I can't create a new question so far, but I have updated my original question already,